# How to solve IIS URL redirection after the url redirection it shows 404 error

Tags: wordpress, redirect, iis

Server Error

404 - File or directory not found.

The resource you are looking for might have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.

```
 <rule name="Redirect1" patternSyntax="ExactMatch" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="faq/us-markets/can-i-trade-us-counters" negate="true" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false" />
                    <action type="Redirect" url="https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask" />
                </rule>
```

```
IIS URL redirection after the url redirection it shows  404 error
```

Comment: 1. Use a private browser tab for testing. 2. Enable FRT and read what it records,  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules

Comment: Which url do you want to redirect from to which url?

Comment: From url=localhost//faq/us-markets/can-i-trade-us-counters
To URL: http://test.dev.com

Comment: Firstly, the url is not a valid address, you should type 1 less `/` after localhost. I have test your URL rewrite rule, It worked if you access `localhost/faq/us-markets/can-i-trade-us-counters`, you can clear the cache and try again, if it still not working, try to enable Failed Request Tracing  to get the specific reason.